# Why Serilog PostgreSQL sink is not working through Configuration?

Tags: .net, serilog, serilog-postgresql

I have tried PostgreSQL sink for Serilog through code and it works like a charm.
**Here is working code:**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var connectionString = "Server=localhost; Port=5432; Database=subscriptions_log; User Id=postgres;Password=postgres";
        string tableName = "errorlog";

        IDictionary<string, ColumnWriterBase> columnWriters = new Dictionary<string, ColumnWriterBase>
        {
            {"message", new RenderedMessageColumnWriter(NpgsqlDbType.Text) },
            {"level", new LevelColumnWriter(true, NpgsqlDbType.Varchar) },
            {"raise_date", new TimestampColumnWriter(NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp) },
            {"exception", new ExceptionColumnWriter(NpgsqlDbType.Text) }
        };

        using var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .WriteTo.PostgreSQL(connectionString, tableName, columnWriters)
            .CreateLogger();

        log.Information("Hello, Serilog!");
    }
```

But when I use it through configuration file serlig creates table in the database but does not insert any rows because of *"Npgsql.NpgsqlBinaryImporter.Complete()"* not found.
**"Here is detailed error:**

```
Exception while emitting periodic batch from Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL.PostgreSQLSink:
        System.MissingMethodException:
        Method not found: 'Void Npgsql.NpgsqlBinaryImporter.Complete()'.
   at Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL.PostgreSQLSink.ProcessEventsByCopyCommand(IEnumerable`1 events, NpgsqlConnection connection)
   at Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL.PostgreSQLSink.EmitBatch(IEnumerable`1 events)
   at Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.PeriodicBatchingSink.EmitBatchAsync(IEnumerable`1 events)
   at Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching.PeriodicBatchingSink.OnTick()
```

**ProjectFile**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine" Version="5.0.0"     />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables"     Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="5.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="2.10.1-dev-01285" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Settings.Configuration" Version="3.2.0-dev-00264" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.Console" Version="4.0.0-dev-00839" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.File" Version="5.0.0-dev-00909" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.PeriodicBatching" Version="2.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL.Configuration" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Config File**

```
        {
        "Serilog": {
            "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL.Configuration" ],
            "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
            "Enrich": [ "WithMachineName" ],
            "WriteTo": [
                {
                    "Name": "PostgreSQL",
                    "Args": {
                        "connectionString": "LogsDb",
                        "tableName": "errorlogs",
                        "needAutoCreateTable": true
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "ConnectionStrings": {
            "LogsDb": "Server=localhost; Port=5432; Database=subscriptions_log; User Id=postgres;Password=postgres"
        },
        "Columns": {
            "message": "RenderedMessageColumnWriter",
            "level": {
                "Name": "LevelColumnWriter",
                "Args": {
                    "renderAsText": true,
                    "dbType": "Varchar"
                }
            },
            "raise_date": "TimestampColumnWriter",
            "exception": "ExceptionColumnWriter"
        }
    }
```

**And the Calling Method:**

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(msg => Debug.WriteLine(msg));
        Serilog.Debugging.SelfLog.Enable(Console.Error);

        IConfiguration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "..", "..", "..")))
            .AddJsonFile("serilog.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables()
            .AddCommandLine(args)
            .Build();

        using var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
            .CreateLogger();

        log.Error("Hello, Serilog!");
    }
```

Configuration file is exactly as described [here](https://github.com/b00ted/serilog-sinks-postgresql). For test purpose I tried with .net 5.0 and 3.1 with out success.
Unfortunately I can't use it through code as I am using a 3rd party library that uses serilog for logging to sql server and I have to switch to PostgrSQL only through configuration. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you get this error is because [Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL/) depends on Npgsql [**v4.0.2**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/4.0.2), but you are forcing an upgrade of Npgsql to [**v5.0.3**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/5.0.3) which is not compatible with the latest version of Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL ([v2.2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL/2.2.0) as of this writing).

```
<PackageReference Include="Npgsql" Version="5.0.3" />
```

- [In version 4.x the return type of the method `NpgsqlBinaryImporter.Complete` is `void`](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/v4.1.8/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlBinaryImporter.cs#L380)
- [In version 5.x the return type of the method `NpgsqlBinaryImporter.Complete` is `ulong`](https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/blob/v5.0.3/src/Npgsql/NpgsqlBinaryImporter.cs#L423)

This is binary breaking change in Npgsql which causes the `MissingMethodException` because... The method expected in 4.x no longer exists in 5.x.

An immediate solution for you, is to remove the `Npgsql` package reference and use v4.2.0 which will be added transitively by Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL. Alternatively you can upgrade Npgsql to the latest 4.x version which is [**v4.1.8**](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Npgsql/4.1.8) as of this writing.

The long-term solution is to open an issue in the repo of [Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL](https://github.com/b00ted/serilog-sinks-postgresql), so that they can release a new version that takes a dependency on Npgsql 5.x.

**Update**: It looks like the [Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL/) is no longer maintained, and there's a fork of available here: https://github.com/SeppPenner/SerilogSinkForPostgreSQL which is up-to-date